# The screen parameters generated by Firebase SDK are not recognized on Google Tag Manager

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, appsflyer

We have implemented Firebase SDK, Google Tag Manager and AppsFlyer for behavior analysis and Marketing campaigns tracking on a hybrid mobile app.

So far, we have tracked several events successfully, but we also need to know the context in which those events take place.

With that objective, as the app runs on a web view and automatic screen tracking only shows "MainActivity", we implemented the manual tracking of the screen views. The implementation was done following Firebase documentation (https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/screenviews#manually_track_screens). The idea was to know the screen on which a given event was generated.

The problem is that the parameters firebase_screen and firebase_screen_class don't arrive to AppsFlyer.

To track the events in AppsFlyer, the events generated by the Firebase SDK trigger tags on GTM. The AppsFlyer tags take the firebase_screen and firebase_screen_class parameters as part of the event value (Figure 1). [Figure 1. AppsFlyer tag on GTM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wA8V.png)

Nonetheless, even when the event arrives to Firebase with the correct parameters (Figure 2), this parameters are not sent to AppsFlyer in the GTM-generated event (see Figure 3 for a screenshot of the ADB Logcat). This issue was detected on 24th August, as until 23rd the parameters were correctly sent through GTM.
[Figure 2 - Firebase Debug View showing that the parameters are correctly configured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chkyf.png)
[Figure 3 - ADB Logcat showing the parameters sent to AppsFlyer, lacking firebase_screen and firebase_screen_class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OOau.png).

We tried to configure a GA4 tag on GTM, but the new event does not arrive to GA4 cause the two parameters firebase_screen and firebase_screen_class are missing.
Nevertheless, when the parameters are hardcoded in the frontend of the app, they are recognized by GTM and arrive to AppsFlyer, but they generate a firebase_error_code 14, which means that a reserved parameter name is being used.